# How to write data into Excel file in order

Tags: java, excel

I need to write data into an Excel file in order.

I've written this function:

```
private void writeXlFile() 
    { 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

    Map<String, List<String>> empData = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    name.add("Employee ID");
    name.add("Employee Name");
    name.add("Salary");
    empData.put("1", name);

    name = new ArrayList<String>();
    name.add("01");
    name.add("bala");
    name.add("100000");
    empData.put("2", name);

    name = new ArrayList<String>();
    name.add("02");
    name.add("Ganesh");
    name.add("100000");
    empData.put("3", name);

    name = new ArrayList<String>();
    name.add("03");
    name.add("Krish");
    name.add("100000");
    empData.put("4", name);

    Set<String> keyset = empData.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset)
    {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        List<String> nameList = empData.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : nameList)
        {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof Date)
            {
                cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
            }
            else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
            {
                cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
            }
            else if (obj instanceof String)
            {
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            }
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
            {
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
            }
        }
    }

    try
    {
        String path = separator + "home" + separator + "santhanam" + separator
                + "Desktop" + separator + "write.xls";
        FileOutputStream out =
                new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException :" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException :" + e);
    }
}
```

It's working, but the result is appearing like this:

```
02          Ganesh          100000
01          bala            100000
Employee ID Employee Name   Salary
03          Kumar           100000
```

I want to write employee id and name as first row in the sheet.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Integer instead of String.

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> empData = new HashMap<Integer , List<String>>();
```

and so on. It will fix your problem.

Thanks
Bipin